# Why i am not able to tweet in arabic language using twitterizer2?

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I'm trying to post tweets from my asp.net application using twitterizer2. When I tweet in english, it works. But when I try to tweet in arabic, it returns unauthenticated error.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitterizer's implementation of OAuth (the security mechanism used by Twitter) doesn't fully support non-English characters.  It's a known issue with the Twitterizer library.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: It would require modifications to the Twitterizier code, specifically the components that build the OAuth encrypted string.  I struggled with this problem in my own Twitter library and eventually gave up because I wasn't able to crack it.  You may want to look into using anther library that has solved this problem.

Comment: what is other library better one?

Comment: You could look into TweetSharp, bu I do not know if it has the same issue or not.